# Object doesn't creating

Tags: delphi, object

I'm creating a non-visual component. Short Code:

```
// Element of some list item
TMyItem = class
private
  Id: integer;
  Caption: string;
public
  constructor Create(const aId: integer; const aCaption: string);
end;

// List of items
TMyItemList = class(TObjectList<TMyItem>)
public
  constructor Create;
end;

// The component
TMyComp = class(TComponent)
private
  FMyList: TMyItemList;
public
  constructor Create;

implementation

constructor TMyComp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FMyList:= TMyItemList.Create;
end;
```

Question: why "FMyList" not exists when "MyComp" created? Assigned(FMyList) = false ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not your actual code. Your actual code compiles. But we can guess what the problem is. Here:

```
type
  TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyList: TMyItemList;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;
```

The constructor for `TComponent` is declared like this:

```
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); virtual;
```

It's a virtual constructor because the Delphi streaming framework relies upon metaclasses to create objects. If you want the framework to call your constructor you have to override this virtual constructor.

```
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
```

I'm reasonably confident of this guess, but we should not need to guess. Next time, please submit real code, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your answer worked, thanks a lot, adding "override" solved the problem. And ok, next time i'll write actual code, i thinked it's enough to write like this.

Comment: It's a really good habit to get into. It will help you find lots of problems yourself which is clearly more productive for you. In this case it was obvious because we've seen this mistake so many times and recognise it well. But until you've learnt it, it's hard for you to spot.

Comment: What @DavidHeffernan did not mention: if you post made up code, then you may introduce errors in the fake code that did not exist in the original. That makes it very hard for someone trying to help to see what the real problem is.

Comment: It also leads to people spending time fixing the made up mistakes only to be told, "oh, the real code is different, it doesn't make those mistakes". Which, I can tell you, is pretty frustrating. So, don't post made up code.  ;-)

Comment: In my case i made up the correct code, so, don't panic=) The reason of this is that im tried to clean up the code that dosen't have any relation to the problem.